# RaspberryPi + Pocketsphinx + ps3eye Error: Failed to open audio device

Tags: audio, speech-recognition, raspberry-pi, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

just installed pocketsphinx on my raspberry pi. Think i'm going crazy but not sure if I'm providing the correct device.

Whenever I run:

> src/programs/pocketsphinx_continuous -adcdev plughw:1,0 -nfft 2048
>   -samprate 48000

I get the following:

> root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8#
>   src/programs/pocketsphinx_continuous -adcdev plughw:1,0 -nfft 2048
>   -samprate 48000  INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line: /usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8/src/programs/.libs/lt-pocketsphinx_continuous
>   \     -adcdev plughw:1,0 \    -nfft 2048 \    -samprate 48000
>
> Current configuration: [NAME]     [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
>   -adcdev               plughw:1,0
>   -agc      none        none
>   -agcthresh    2.0     2.000000e+00
>   -alpha        0.97        9.700000e-01
>   -argfile
>   -ascale       20.0        2.000000e+01
>   -aw       1       1
>   -backtrace    no      no
>   -beam     1e-48       1.000000e-48
>   -bestpath yes     yes
>   -bestpathlw   9.5     9.500000e+00
>   -bghist       no      no
>   -ceplen       13      13
>   -cmn      current     current
>   -cmninit  8.0     8.0
>   -compallsen   no      no
>   -debug                0
>   -dict
>   -dictcase no      no
>   -dither       no      no
>   -doublebw no      no
>   -ds       1       1
>   -fdict
>   -feat     1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
>   -featparams
>   -fillprob 1e-8        1.000000e-08
>   -frate        100     100
>   -fsg
>   -fsgusealtpron    yes     yes
>   -fsgusefiller yes     yes
>   -fwdflat  yes     yes
>   -fwdflatbeam  1e-64       1.000000e-64
>   -fwdflatefwid 4       4
>   -fwdflatlw    8.5     8.500000e+00
>   -fwdflatsfwin 25      25
>   -fwdflatwbeam 7e-29       7.000000e-29
>   -fwdtree  yes     yes
>   -hmm
>   -infile
>   -input_endian little      little
>   -jsgf
>   -kdmaxbbi -1      -1
>   -kdmaxdepth   0       0
>   -kdtree
>   -latsize  5000        5000
>   -lda
>   -ldadim       0       0
>   -lextreedump  0       0
>   -lifter       0       0
>   -lm
>   -lmctl
>   -lmname       default     default
>   -logbase  1.0001      1.000100e+00
>   -logfn
>   -logspec  no      no
>   -lowerf       133.33334   1.333333e+02
>   -lpbeam       1e-40       1.000000e-40
>   -lponlybeam   7e-29       7.000000e-29
>   -lw       6.5     6.500000e+00
>   -maxhmmpf -1      -1
>   -maxnewoov    20      20
>   -maxwpf       -1      -1
>   -mdef
>   -mean
>   -mfclogdir
>   -min_endfr    0       0
>   -mixw
>   -mixwfloor    0.0000001   1.000000e-07
>   -mllr
>   -mmap     yes     yes
>   -ncep     13      13
>   -nfft     512     2048
>   -nfilt        40      40
>   -nwpen        1.0     1.000000e+00
>   -pbeam        1e-48       1.000000e-48
>   -pip      1.0     1.000000e+00
>   -pl_beam  1e-10       1.000000e-10
>   -pl_pbeam 1e-5        1.000000e-05
>   -pl_window    0       0
>   -rawlogdir
>   -remove_dc    no      no
>   -round_filters    yes     yes
>   -samprate 16000       4.800000e+04
>   -seed     -1      -1
>   -sendump
>   -senlogdir
>   -senmgau
>   -silprob  0.005       5.000000e-03
>   -smoothspec   no      no
>   -svspec
>   -time     no      no
>   -tmat
>   -tmatfloor    0.0001      1.000000e-04
>   -topn     4       4
>   -topn_beam    0       0
>   -toprule
>   -transform    legacy      legacy
>   -unit_area    yes     yes
>   -upperf       6855.4976   6.855498e+03
>   -usewdphones  no      no
>   -uw       1.0     1.000000e+00
>   -var
>   -varfloor 0.0001      1.000000e-04
>   -varnorm  no      no
>   -verbose  no      no
>   -warp_params
>   -warp_type    inverse_linear  inverse_linear
>   -wbeam        7e-29       7.000000e-29
>   -wip      0.65        6.500000e-01
>   -wlen     0.025625    2.562500e-02
>
> INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line: \  -nfilt 20 \     -lowerf 1 \
>     -upperf 4000 \  -wlen 0.025 \   -transform dct \    -round_filters no \
>     -remove_dc yes \    -svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38 \  -feat 1s_c_d_dd \   -agc
>   none \    -cmn current \  -cmninit 56,-3,1 \  -varnorm no
>
> Current configuration: [NAME]     [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
>   -agc      none        none
>   -agcthresh    2.0     2.000000e+00
>   -alpha        0.97        9.700000e-01
>   -ceplen       13      13
>   -cmn      current     current
>   -cmninit  8.0     56,-3,1
>   -dither       no      no
>   -doublebw no      no
>   -feat     1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
>   -frate        100     100
>   -input_endian little      little
>   -lda
>   -ldadim       0       0
>   -lifter       0       0
>   -logspec  no      no
>   -lowerf       133.33334   1.000000e+00
>   -ncep     13      13
>   -nfft     512     2048
>   -nfilt        40      20
>   -remove_dc    no      yes
>   -round_filters    yes     no
>   -samprate 16000       4.800000e+04
>   -seed     -1      -1
>   -smoothspec   no      no
>   -svspec               0-12/13-25/26-38
>   -transform    legacy      dct
>   -unit_area    yes     yes
>   -upperf       6855.4976   4.000000e+03
>   -varnorm  no      no
>   -verbose  no      no
>   -warp_params
>   -warp_type    inverse_linear  inverse_linear
>   -wlen     0.025625    2.500000e-02
>
> INFO: acmod.c(246): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from
>   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/feat.params
>   INFO: feat.c(713): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd',
>   ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none' INFO: cmn.c(142):
>   mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0 INFO: acmod.c(167): Using subvector
>   specification 0-12/13-25/26-38 INFO: mdef.c(517): Reading model
>   definition:
>   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/mdef INFO:
>   mdef.c(528): Found byte-order mark BMDF, assuming this is a binary
>   mdef file INFO: bin_mdef.c(336): Reading binary model definition:
>   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/mdef INFO:
>   bin_mdef.c(513): 50 CI-phone, 143047 CD-phone, 3 emitstate/phone, 150
>   CI-sen, 5150 Sen, 27135 Sen-Seq INFO: tmat.c(205): Reading HMM
>   transition probability matrices:
>   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/transition_matrices
>   INFO: acmod.c(121): Attempting to use SCHMM computation module INFO:
>   ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter:
>   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/means
>   INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1 codebook, 3 feature, size:  INFO:
>   ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13 INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13 INFO:
>   ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13 INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture
>   gaussian parameter:
>   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/variances
>   INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1 codebook, 3 feature, size:  INFO:
>   ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13 INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13 INFO:
>   ms_gauden.c(294):  256x13 INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 0 variance values
>   floored INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(903): Loading senones from dump file
>   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/sendump
>   INFO: s2_semi_mgau.c(927): BEGIN FILE FORMAT DESCRIPTION INFO:
>   s2_semi_mgau.c(1022): Using memory-mapped I/O for senones INFO:
>   s2_semi_mgau.c(1296): Maximum top-N: 4 Top-N beams: 0 0 0 INFO:
>   dict.c(317): Allocating 137543 * 20 bytes (2686 KiB) for word entries
>   INFO: dict.c(332): Reading main dictionary:
>   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/lm/en_US/cmu07a.dic INFO:
>   dict.c(211): Allocated 1010 KiB for strings, 1664 KiB for phones INFO:
>   dict.c(335): 133436 words read INFO: dict.c(341): Reading filler
>   dictionary:
>   /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k/noisedict
>   INFO: dict.c(211): Allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones INFO:
>   dict.c(344): 11 words read INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables
>   for dictionary INFO: dict2pid.c(404): Allocating 50^3 * 2 bytes (244
>   KiB) for word-initial triphones INFO: dict2pid.c(131): Allocated 30200
>   bytes (29 KiB) for word-final triphones INFO: dict2pid.c(195):
>   Allocated 30200 bytes (29 KiB) for single-phone word triphones INFO:
>   ngram_model_arpa.c(77): No \data\ mark in LM file INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(142): Will use memory-mapped I/O for LM file INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(196): ngrams 1=5001, 2=436879, 3=418286 INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(242):     5001 = LM.unigrams(+trailer) read INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(288):   436879 = LM.bigrams(+trailer) read INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(314):   418286 = LM.trigrams read INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(339):    37293 = LM.prob2 entries read INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(359):    14370 = LM.bo_wt2 entries read INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(379):    36094 = LM.prob3 entries read INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(407):      854 = LM.tseg_base entries read INFO:
>   ngram_model_dmp.c(463):     5001 = ascii word strings read INFO:
>   ngram_search_fwdtree.c(99): 788 unique initial diphones INFO:
>   ngram_search_fwdtree.c(147): 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 60
>   single-phone words INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(186): Creating search
>   tree INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(191): before: 0 root, 0 non-root
>   channels, 60 single-phone words INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(326):
>   after: max nonroot chan increased to 13428 INFO:
>   ngram_search_fwdtree.c(338): after: 457 root, 13300 non-root channels,
>   26 single-phone words INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(156): fwdflat:
>   min_ef_width = 4, max_sf_win = 25 INFO: continuous.c(371):
>   /usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8/src/programs/.libs/lt-pocketsphinx_continuous
>   COMPILED ON: Jul 21 2013, AT: 14:34:06
>
> Mixer load failed: Invalid argument FATAL_ERROR: "continuous.c", line
>   246: Failed to open audio device

I'm using a ps3eye currently. If i do a simple:

> arecord -D plughw:1,0 -d 5 -q -f cd -t wav ~/test.wav

Everything works fine ( Verified this by hooking up Raspberrypi to TV via HDMI and running aplay ~/test.wav )

What am I doing wrong guys?

Information you might need ( based on other posts i've seen ):

```
root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8# 
root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8# aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=ALSA
    bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA
    Default Audio Device
root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8#



root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8# dpkg -l | grep "alsa"
ii  alsa-base                             1.0.25+3~deb7u1                      all          ALSA driver configuration files
ii  alsa-firmware-loaders                 1.0.25-2                             armhf        ALSA software loaders for specific hardware
ii  alsa-oss                              1.0.25-1                             armhf        ALSA wrapper for OSS applications
ii  alsa-tools                            1.0.25-2                             armhf        Console based ALSA utilities for specific hardware
ii  alsa-utils                            1.0.25-4                             armhf        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
ii  alsaplayer-alsa                       0.99.80-5.1                          armhf        PCM player designed for ALSA (ALSA output module)
ii  alsaplayer-common                     0.99.80-5.1                          armhf        PCM player designed for ALSA (common files)
ii  alsaplayer-gtk                        0.99.80-5.1                          armhf        PCM player designed for ALSA (GTK+ version)
ii  gstreamer0.10-alsa:armhf              0.10.36-1.1                          armhf        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
ii  libsox-fmt-alsa                       14.4.0-3                             armhf        SoX alsa format I/O library
root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8#



root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8# dpkg -l | grep pulseaudio
ii  gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio:armhf        0.10.31-3+nmu1                       armhf        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8#
```

Also in terms of installing pocket sphinx I did the following:

```
# uninstall pulse audio if its already installed 
apt-get remove pulseaudio -y 
aptitude purge pulseaudio -y

# sphinxbase install
apt-get install bison -y
cd /usr/install
wget  http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/cmusphinx/sphinxbase/0.8/sphinxbase-0.8.tar.gz
tar -xvf sphinxbase-0.8.tar.gz
cd sphinxbase-0.8
./configure
make
make install
cd -

# pocketsphinx installwget http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/pocketsphinx/0.8/pocketsphinx-0.8.tar.gz
tar -xvf pocketsphinx-0.8.tar.gz
cd pocketsphinx-0.8
./configure
make
make install
```

Any ideas or advice in the right direction would be extremely helpful.

Thanks,

Malcolm Jones

EDIT:

Forgot to include this information as well:

```
root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8# arecord -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=CameraB409241
    USB Camera-B4.09.24.1, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=CameraB409241,DEV=0
    USB Camera-B4.09.24.1, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=CameraB409241,DEV=0
    USB Camera-B4.09.24.1, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=CameraB409241,DEV=0
    USB Camera-B4.09.24.1, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=CameraB409241,DEV=0
    USB Camera-B4.09.24.1, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=CameraB409241,DEV=0
    USB Camera-B4.09.24.1, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=CameraB409241,DEV=0
    USB Camera-B4.09.24.1, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=CameraB409241,DEV=0
    USB Camera-B4.09.24.1, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
root@scarlettpi:/usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8#
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Took me a while, with with some help from a couple sources ( they will be listed in my answer ) and some helpful hints from [nikolay-shmyrev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432021/nikolay-shmyrev), I finally came up with an answer that worked for me.

Key assumptions:

1. running these commands as the pi user ( previously I was running them as root, which was incorrect )
2. I'm using continuous recognition and I was ONLY looking for the ability to "wake-up" my raspberry pi. Upon waking it up, I have other plans on how it should interact.

My setup:

1. Canakit RaspberryPi
2. HDMI cable to my Toshiba TV
3. usb wifi dongle
4. Playstation 3 Eye for speech recognition

Moving forward. I ran the following commands on my RaspberryPi to get PulseAudio + pocketsphinx working together w/ my Playstation 3 Eye. ( If you see any places for improvement please let me know )

### Install pulse audio / development packages

```sh
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio libao4 libasound2-plugins libgconfmm-2.6-1c2 libglademm-2.4-1c2a libpulse-dev libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse-mainloop-glib0-dbg libpulse0 libpulse0-dbg libsox-fmt-pulse paman paprefs pavucontrol pavumeter pulseaudio pulseaudio-dbg pulseaudio-esound-compat pulseaudio-esound-compat-dbg pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-gconf pulseaudio-module-jack pulseaudio-module-lirc pulseaudio-module-lirc-dbg pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-module-zeroconf pulseaudio-module-zeroconf-dbg pulseaudio-utils oss-compat -y
```

### Setting up ALSA

Per instructions from http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=12497

```sh
sudo \cp -pf /etc/asound.conf /etc/asound.conf.ORIG 
echo 'pcm.pulse {
    type pulse
}

ctl.pulse {
    type pulse
}

pcm.!default {
    type pulse
}

ctl.!default {
    type pulse
}' | sudo tee /etc/asound.conf
```

### Make sure your camera device loads on boot

```sh
_DEVICE_LOAD_ON_START=$(grep "snd.bcm2835" /etc/modules | wc -l)
if [[ "${_DEVICE_LOAD_ON_START}" = "0" ]]; then

  sudo \cp -pf /etc/modules /etc/modules.ORIG
  echo "snd-bcm2835" | tee -a /etc/modules

fi

# Disallow module loading after startup. This is a security feature since it disallows additional module loading during runtime and on user request.
_DISALLOW_MODULE_LOADING=$(grep "DISALLOW_MODULE_LOADING=1" /etc/default/pulseaudio | wc -l)
if [[ "${_DISALLOW_MODULE_LOADING}" = "0" ]]; then

  sudo \cp -pf /etc/default/pulseaudio /etc/default/pulseaudio.ORIG
  sudo sed -i "s,DISALLOW_MODULE_LOADING=1,DISALLOW_MODULE_LOADING=0,g" /etc/default/pulseaudio

fi
```

### Set up the PulseAudio daemon for network connections

```sh
# allow other clients on the network to connect to pulseaudio daemon ( only add auth-anonymous=1 if you know EVERY machine on your LAN ... this could be a security risk otherwise )
sudo \cp -fvp /etc/pulse/system.pa /etc/pulse/system.pa.ORIG
echo "
# ScarlettPi ADDED THIS
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.0.0/24 auth-anonymous=1
load-module module-zeroconf-publish" | sudo tee -a /etc/pulse/system.pa

echo "
# ScarlettPi added this
#load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
#load-module module-zeroconf-publish
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.0.0/24 auth-anonymous=1
load-module module-zeroconf-publish" | sudo tee -a /etc/pulse/default.pa

# check to make sure it looks okay
cat /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

### Change default sound driver from alsa to pulseaudio

```sh
sudo \cp -fvp /etc/libao.conf /etc/libao.conf.ORIG
sudo sed -i "s,default_driver=alsa,default_driver=pulse,g" /etc/libao.conf 

# daemon settings according to Pi-Musicbox ( https://github.com/woutervanwijk/Pi-MusicBox )
sudo \cp -fvp /etc/pulse/daemon.conf /etc/pulse/daemon.conf.ORIG

echo "
# ScarlettPi added this
high-priority = yes
nice-level = 5
exit-idle-time = -1
resample-method = src-sinc-medium-quality
default-sample-format = s16le
default-sample-rate = 48000
default-sample-channels = 2" | sudo tee -a /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

### Add `pi` user to the pulse access group

```sh
sudo adduser pi pulse-access

# shut down the machine to make sure all the settings we just made are loaded correctly
sudo shutdown -r now
```

### Make sure to add `/usr/local/lib` to library path

```sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

# also add these to your .bashrc so they get set once you login 
echo "
# scarlettPi added this
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig" | tee -a ~/.bashrc
```

### Install base PocketSphinx

```sh
# install python dev packages
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev -y

# sphinxbase install ( required to install pocketsphinx )
sudo apt-get install bison -y
cd ~pi/
wget  http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/cmusphinx/sphinxbase/0.8/sphinxbase-0.8.tar.gz
tar -xvf sphinxbase-0.8.tar.gz
cd sphinxbase-0.8
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd -

# pocketsphinx install
# set this: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/pocketsphinxlibs /usr/local/bin/pocketsphinx_continuous
# http://www.voxforge.org/home/forums/message-boards/speech-recognition-engines/howto-use-pocketsphinx
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/pocketsphinx/0.8/pocketsphinx-0.8.tar.gz
tar -xvf pocketsphinx-0.8.tar.gz
cd pocketsphinx-0.8
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd -

# install sphinxtrain
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinxtrain/1.0.8/sphinxtrain-1.0.8.tar.gz
tar -xvf sphinxtrain-1.0.8
cd sphinxtrain-1.0.8
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd -
```

### Check if pulse daemon is running

```sh
ps aux | grep pulse

# If it isn't, start it up yourself ( need to figure out the best way to make this run on boot...init.d script maybe? )
/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog --system=false
```

### Finally, run Sphinx

**IMPORTANT NOTE**
YOU HAVE TO BE USER PI AND THE PULSEAUDIO SERVER NEEDS TO BE RUNNING

Assumimg existing corpus file, .jsgf file, .dic, and .lm files (using [lmtool](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool.html))

```sh
cd ~pi/pocketsphinx-0.8
pocketsphinx_continuous -lm /home/pi/scarlettPi/config/speech/lm/scarlett.lm -dict /home/pi/scarlettPi/config/speech/dict/scarlett.dic -hmm /home/pi/scarlettPi/config/speech/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k -silprob  0.1 -wip 1e-4 -bestpath 0
```

References:

- [Advice on how to calibrate pocketsphinx correctly](http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/49e34dff/)
- [How to get pocketsphinx to recognize new words via a corpus](http://www.ghatage.com/2012/12/make-pocketsphinx-recognize-new-words/)
- [BEST/Simplest explanation of how Java Speech Grammar Format works](http://puneetk.com/basics-of-java-speech-grammar-format-jsgf)

I plan on adding more details behind why I used certain setting, configurations in a blog post i'm writing on my home automation project, but figured, i'd share what i've done thus far incase someone else was stuck like me and would like to move forward with what they're working on. Hope this helps someone. Thanks for the advice guys.

Comment: This is an excellent resource! In my system, i kept seeing "Error opening audio device (null) for capture: Connection refused" when running  pocketsphinx_continuous.  I worked around it by "export PULSE_SERVER=127.0.0.1", but didn't really understand why that was necessary to make pocketsphinx_continuous work.

Comment: @JoaoCosta glad it was able to help! I should mention that this post is extremely old at this point as it is using an older cmusphinx, and pulse audio. Settings have probably changed a lot since 2013. Recommended to use the latest pocket sphinx  ( you can find it on github under the cmusphinx organization ). Also depending on the version of pulse audio you have running, you can look up the docs on the options configurations ( those values change through the years as well ).

Answer (score 2):

> apt-get remove pulseaudio -y 
>   aptitude purge pulseaudio -y

If you don't know how to configure alsa, you should better use pulseaudio, moreover, it's configured on your system. You should better compile sphinxbase with pulseaudio support. For more information read the FAQ:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qfailed_to_open_audio_device_dev_dsp_no_such_file_or_directory

> Mixer load failed: Invalid argument

This is a key message, it says that your alsa configuration doesn't support level mixer. If you don't know how to add mixer in alsa configuration, use pulseaudio

> ./configure --enable-fixed

This is a bad idea too which will reduce both speed and accuracy on your device. Your processor has FPU, so you shouldn't use fixed point mode.

Comment: Hey Nikolay,

Thanks a lot for the suggestions. I did a "make uninstall" on both sphinxbase and pocketsphinx, installed the following packages:

apt-get install pulseaudio pulseaudio-dbg libpulse-dev libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulse0-dbg pulseaudio-esound-compat pulseaudio-esound-compat-dbg libpulse-dev pulseaudio-module-zeroconf -y 

Then I recompiled both basesphinx and pocketsphinx ( without that config option as suggested ). I'm assuming by simply having the pulseaudio dev package present, both base/pocket complied against it correctly or do i need to specify something?

Comment: Also, I think i'm a little unclear on how to use pulseaudio w/ pocketsphix, any other links etc you can recommend I look at as I go w/ this debugging journey? Still a little uncertain what device I should now use since i'm attempting this with pulseaudio. Again thank you for your help thus far.

Comment: You can just use it, there is no need to specify anything.

Comment: Hey Nikolay,

Tried running the following from the command line:

pocketsphinx_continuous -mftt=512 -samprate 48000 -lm /usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8/custom_language/en_model.lm -dict /usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8/custom_language/cmudict.hub4.06d.dict -hmm /usr/install/pocketsphinx-0.8/model/hmm

and got the following:

INFO: continuous.c(371): pocketsphinx_continuous COMPILED ON: Jul 22 2013, AT: 01:21:55

Error opening audio device (null) for capture: Connection refused
FATAL_ERROR: "continuous.c", line 246: Failed to open audio device

Any thoughts?

Comment: One last thing Nikolay, I've been keeping track of all my progress here. I even attached some debugging information from a script I got off of the alsa website ( dont worry i'm still trying to use pulseaudio ). Details here: http://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/1itr9h/how_to_compile_use_pocketsphinx_w_pulseaudio_on/

Comment: "Connection refused" means you didn't start pulseaudio daemon

Comment: Realized 2 things, one, I ran the pulseaudio daemon as root & in system wide mode ( which is not recommended ). Added pi user to pulse group, audio group, then su pi, and attempted to run pocketsphinx again. Looks like its running. Going to test again later tonight with a .dict, .lm, & corpus file I created to see if I get the correct recognition results. Will post my steps as well.

Comment: "Connection refused" can also mean the client is not able to "find" the server, ie, "pactl --server 127.0.0.1 info" works, but "pactl info" doesn't.  Not sure why this happens, but a workaround is to "export PULSE_SERVER=127.0.0.1"

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem of failing to open audio device.

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qfailed_to_open_audio_device_dev_dsp_no_such_file_or_directory

I fix it buy installing libpulse-dev package then reinstall sphinxbase , pocketsphinx.