# Fundamental issue with my Gstreamer pipeline logic in Python. Any advice?

Tags: python, linux, cmusphinx, gstreamer

I have the following piece of code:

```
import pi
from pi.becore import ScarlettConfig
from recorder import Recorder
from brain import Brain

import os
import json
import tempfile
#import sys

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import gobject
import pygst
pygst.require('0.10')
gobject.threads_init()
import gst

scarlett_config=ScarlettConfig()

class Listener:
  def __init__(self, gobject, gst):
    self.failed = 0
    # scarlettPi ( mmj2f I added this after attempting the scarlettPi change )
    self.recording = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='pi.wav')

    self.pipeline = gst.Pipeline("mypipeline")

    # alsasrc - we'll use this to connect our ps3 eye and record 
    gst.debug("Adding alsasrc")
    self.source  = gst.element_factory_make("alsasrc", "alsasrc")
    self.source.set_property("device", scarlett_config.gimmie('audio_input_device'))
    self.pipeline.add(self.source)

    # add a queue to allow pocketsphinx to recognize more data
    gst.debug("Adding encoding queue")
    self.qone = gst.element_factory_make("queue", "qone")
    self.pipeline.add(self.qone)

    # audio convert
    gst.debug("Adding encoding audioconvert")
    self.recfileconvert = gst.element_factory_make("audioconvert", "recfileconvert")
    self.pipeline.add(self.recfileconvert)

    # resample the wav
    gst.debug("Adding encoding audioresample")
    self.resample = gst.element_factory_make("audioresample", "resample")
    self.pipeline.add(self.resample)

    # Add our tee
    gst.debug("Adding tee")
    self.rectee = gst.element_factory_make("tee", "rectee")
    self.pipeline.add(self.rectee)

    # taken from: http://www.jonobacon.org/files/recgui-works.py
    # link tee to alsasrc
    gst.debug("Linking alsasrc to tee")
    self.source.link(self.rectee)

    gst.debug("Adding encoding queue")
    self.qtwo = gst.element_factory_make("queue", "qtwo")
    self.pipeline.add(self.qtwo)

    gst.debug("Adding vader element")
    self.vader = gst.element_factory_make("vader","vader")
    self.vader.set_property("auto-threshold",False)
    self.pipeline.add(self.vader)

    gst.debug("Adding pocketsphinx element")
    self.pocketsphinx = gst.element_factory_make("pocketsphinx","listener")
    print "Pocketsphinx: "
    print dir( self.pocketsphinx )
    self.pocketsphinx.set_property("lm",scarlett_config.gimmie('LM'))
    self.pocketsphinx.set_property("dict",scarlett_config.gimmie('DICT'))
    self.pocketsphinx.set_property("hmm",scarlett_config.gimmie('HMM'))

    gst.debug("Adding fakesink")
    self.fakesink = gst.element_factory_make("fakesink", "fakesink")
    self.fakesink.set_property("dump", True)
    self.pipeline.add(self.fakesink)

    # Linking fakesink to tee
    # taken from: http://www.jonobacon.org/files/recgui-works.py
    gst.debug("Linking fakesink to tee")
    self.fakesink.link(self.rectee)

    # creating valve now
    gst.debug("Adding Valve element")
    self.recording_valve = gst.element_factory_make('valve')
    self.record_valve.set_property("drop",False)
    self.pipeline.add(self.recording_valve)

    # another queue
    gst.debug("Adding encoding queue")
    self.recording_valve_queue = gst.element_factory_make("queue", "recording_valve_queue")
    self.pipeline.add(self.recording_valve_queue)
    self.recording_valve.link (self.recording_valve_queue)

    # adding wavenc element
    gst.debug("Adding wavenc")
    self.wavenc = gst.element_factory_make("wavenc", "wavenc")
    self.pipeline.add(self.wavenc)

    # adding filesink element 
    gst.debug("Adding filesink")
    self.filesink = gst.element_factory_make("filesink", "filesink")
    self.filesink.set_property("location", self.recording)
    self.filesink.set_property("async", False)
    self.pipeline.add(self.filesink)

    # lets add the static pads now and link them?
    # NOTE: Not sure if this is correct at all:
    # self.rectee_pad = self.rectee.get_request_pad("src%d")
    # print "Obtained request pad %s for audio branch."% self.rectee_pad.get_name()    
    self.rectee.get_request_pad('src%d').link(self.recording_valve_queue.get_pad('sink'))
    self.rectee.get_request_pad('src%d').link(self.qtwo.get_pad('sink'))

    # Original code going forward:
    listener = self.pipeline.get_by_name('listener')
    listener.connect('result', self.__result__)
    listener.set_property('configured', True)
    print "KEYWORDS WE'RE LOOKING FOR: " + scarlett_config.gimmie('ourkeywords')

......ETC..........
```

And I'm getting this error when I try to run my script:

```
pi@scarlettpi ~/dev/scarlettPi/scripts/pi $ pi
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line:
gst-pocketsphinx \
    -samprate 8000 \
    -cmn prior \
    -fwdflat no \
    -bestpath no \
    -maxhmmpf 2000 \
    -maxwpf 20 

Current configuration:
[NAME]      [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
-agc        none        none
-agcthresh  2.0     2.000000e+00
-alpha      0.97        9.700000e-01
-ascale     20.0        2.000000e+01
-aw     1       1
-backtrace  no      no
-beam       1e-48       1.000000e-48
-bestpath   no      no
-bestpathlw 9.5     9.500000e+00
-bghist     no      no
-ceplen     13      13
-cmn        current     prior
-cmninit    8.0     8.0
-compallsen no      no
-debug              0
-dict               
-dictcase   no      no
-dither     no      no
-doublebw   no      no
-ds     1       1
-fdict              
-feat       1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
-featparams         
-fillprob   1e-8        1.000000e-08
-frate      100     100
-fsg                
-fsgusealtpron  yes     yes
-fsgusefiller   yes     yes
-fwdflat    yes     no
-fwdflatbeam    1e-64       1.000000e-64
-fwdflatefwid   4       4
-fwdflatlw  8.5     8.500000e+00
-fwdflatsfwin   25      25
-fwdflatwbeam   7e-29       7.000000e-29
-fwdtree    yes     yes
-hmm                
-input_endian   little      little
-jsgf               
-kdmaxbbi   -1      -1
-kdmaxdepth 0       0
-kdtree             
-latsize    5000        5000
-lda                
-ldadim     0       0
-lextreedump    0       0
-lifter     0       0
-lm             
-lmctl              
-lmname     default     default
-logbase    1.0001      1.000100e+00
-logfn              
-logspec    no      no
-lowerf     133.33334   1.333333e+02
-lpbeam     1e-40       1.000000e-40
-lponlybeam 7e-29       7.000000e-29
-lw     6.5     6.500000e+00
-maxhmmpf   -1      2000
-maxnewoov  20      20
-maxwpf     -1      20
-mdef               
-mean               
-mfclogdir          
-min_endfr  0       0
-mixw               
-mixwfloor  0.0000001   1.000000e-07
-mllr               
-mmap       yes     yes
-ncep       13      13
-nfft       512     512
-nfilt      40      40
-nwpen      1.0     1.000000e+00
-pbeam      1e-48       1.000000e-48
-pip        1.0     1.000000e+00
-pl_beam    1e-10       1.000000e-10
-pl_pbeam   1e-5        1.000000e-05
-pl_window  0       0
-rawlogdir          
-remove_dc  no      no
-round_filters  yes     yes
-samprate   16000       8.000000e+03
-seed       -1      -1
-sendump            
-senlogdir          
-senmgau            
-silprob    0.1     1.000000e-01
-smoothspec no      no
-svspec             
-tmat               
-tmatfloor  0.0001      1.000000e-04
-topn       4       4
-topn_beam  0       0
-toprule            
-transform  legacy      legacy
-unit_area  yes     yes
-upperf     6855.4976   6.855498e+03
-usewdphones    no      no
-uw     1.0     1.000000e+00
-var                
-varfloor   0.0001      1.000000e-04
-varnorm    no      no
-verbose    no      no
-warp_params            
-warp_type  inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wbeam      7e-29       7.000000e-29
-wip        1e-4        1.000000e-04
-wlen       0.025625    2.562500e-02

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pi", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('pi==0.1.0', 'pi')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 499, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1235, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pi-0.1.0-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/pi", line 38, in <module>
    listener = Listener(gobject, gst)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pi-0.1.0-py2.7.egg/pi/listener.py", line 103, in __init__
    self.pocketsphinx.link(self.rectee)
gst.LinkError: failed to link listener with rectee
```

I'm trying to do the following suggestion, but i'm not sure if i'm doing it correctly:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18228933/814221

Can anyone help me understand what i'm doing wrong fundamentally?

Thanks!

Comment: @HarvardGraff posted this here in this question as well just in case ( linked to the other question you're currently helping me with ). Let me know if you have any thoughts my friend!

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: @HavardGraff hey man, yup I def saw your answer, just been having some fundamental issues w/ python I think at this point. Based on your instructions, here's my revised listener.py: http://pastebin.com/5paUJ9MS , recorder.py: http://pastebin.com/1S9PR5mu, trace w/ error: http://pastebin.com/siNGzMvx so just going through the motions. at a minimum how does the gstreamer stuff look?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the capsfilters.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @HavardGraff hey man, yup I def saw your answer, just been having some fundamental issues w/ python I think at this point. Based on your instructions, here's my revised listener.py: pastebin.com/5paUJ9MS , recorder.py: pastebin.com/1S9PR5mu, trace w/ error: pastebin.com/siNGzMvx so just going through the motions. At a minimum how does the gstreamer stuff look?

Comment: I would suggest restructuring the code a bit. Make a pipeline.py class that sets up all the elements, and then just add the exteriors for the listener and the recorder that both uses the same pipeline. The problem in that pastebin is that recording_valve is Null, so it was not able to get it, which could be that the the listener has not added it to the pipeline at that point.

Comment: @HavardGraff I think I Finally got it last night! Before seeing this comment I actually did just that ( also I was trying to get an element using the incorrect name, which is why recording_vavle was null ). Updated code: listener.py - http://pastebin.com/5paUJ9MS recorder.py - http://pastebin.com/1S9PR5mu .... Issue i'm getting now is past the gstreamer part, so I think it actually is working now!!